# Error in ODE Solver in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, sympy, ode

I'm working with a Spark Combustion Engine Model and because some reasons I'm using python to model the combustion. I'm trying to use the solver of ODEs but the yield is completly out of reality. I discovered that the integration of Volume of cylinder is wrong. I have already tried use the "odeint" and "ode" solver but the result is the same. 
The code shows the derivative of Volume with theta and integrate to find the volume. I put the analytical equation to compare.

OBS: I had a similar problem using Matlab, but was when I tried use degrees in trigonometric functions. When I changed for radians the problem was solved.
The code follows:

```
from scipy.integrate import odeint
from scipy.integrate import ode
from scipy import integrate
import math
import sympy
from sympy import sqrt, sin, cos, tan, atan
from pylab import *
from RatesComp import *
V_real=np.zeros((100))

def Volume(V,theta):
   V_sol = V[0]
   dVdtheta = Vtdc*(r-1)/2 *( sin(theta) + eps/2*sin(2*theta)/sqrt(1-(eps**2)*sin(theta)**2))
   return [dVdtheta]

#Geometry
eps = 0.25;        #  half stroke to rod ratio, s/2l
r = 10;            #  compression ratio
Vtdc = 6.9813e-05  # volume at TDC

# Initial Conditions
theta0 = - pi
V_init =  0.0006283
theta = linspace(-pi,pi,100)
solve = odeint( Volume, V_init, theta)

# Analytical Result
Size = len(theta)

for i in range(0, Size,1):
    V_real[i] = Vtdc*(1+(r-1)/2*(1-cos(theta[i])+ 1/eps*(1-(1-(eps**2)*sin(theta[i])**2)**0.5)))

figure(1)
plot(theta, solve[:,0],label="Comput")
plot(theta, V_real[0:Size],label="Real")
ylabel('Volume [m^3]')
xlabel('CA [Rad]')
legend()
grid(True)
show()
```

The fig that I show is the volume of cylinder. The result real and the compute

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MIoEV.png]

Can someone help with information about why this problem happens?

Comment: Do you get the same behavior if you increase the size of your vector theta?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently you use python2. There the declaration of `r=10` gives `r` the type `integer` which leads to a unwanted integer division in `(r-1)/2` in the 'real' solution. In the derivative function there is a float value `Vtdc` as first factor in the product, after which the whole product evaluation is in float.

Thus change to `r=10.0` or use `(r-1.0)/2` or `0.5*(r-1)`.

---

And you should also set `V_init = r*Vtdc` as that is the value of `V_real(-pi)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you use python2 add at the first line: `from __future__ import division` to use division from Python3 according to documentation: https://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2008-March/060886.html

In python2 when you divide two integer values you will get an integer result not float. It is may be solve your problem without large changing in the code.